# How can I get JAWS screen reader to read '_' as 'underscore' instead of 'underline'?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I have an anchor `<a href="mailto:abc_xyz@ggg.com">`

When I am using Jaws to read through this anchor. Jaws is reading the text as "send mail link abc underline xyz @ggn.com"

Is this a known behaviour for Jaws screen reader where it reads underscore as underline? 
If not then what needs to be changed in the anchor to make JAWS read it as underscore.

Jaws version: 2019.1912.1 and Default JAWS settings are in place.

Comment: If this is not a known behaviour of the application then the followup question would be what changes must be made to the code to make the application read it as underscore instead of underline.

Comment: And if it does, will not regular users of Jaws have come to expect this behaviour? What are you seeking to change?

Comment: Your initial question should have been "How can I get it to read as underline instead of underscore?" I would have accepted that...maybe

Comment: Just wanted to clear this ambiguity around the default behaviour. If this is default behaviour, nothing can be changed. If it is not, then something is missing/wrong in my code which is making JAWS behave in this manner.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the insights on rephrasing the question. I've rephrased it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

This is expected behaviour so you do not need to do anything to change this.

### Longer Answer

Except you kind of do need to do something, change the email address format!

Older versions of NVDA will not read the underscore at all in some circumstances, making that email address completely inaccessible!

[See this article on special characters from Deque.com](https://www.deque.com/blog/dont-screen-readers-read-whats-screen-part-1-punctuation-typographic-symbols/) (a little out of date as latest NVDA will work correctly but there are still plenty of people using older versions and a lot of it is still relevant.)

**The real question is:** why on earth would you use an underscore in an email address instead of the accepted fullstop / period for separating words / names?

Most people would not know how to type an `_` so it makes it a bad practice overall.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Since this is a default behaviour nothing can be done for it.
The email used is provided by the firm so had to use that. I will let them know the accepted separator convention for email.

Comment: They should just be able to set up new accounts and forward all incoming mail from the old accounts. Then just update their business cards etc. when the time comes so they can do it gradually without any additional cost. I believe on 365 it is the same as gmail where underscores are actually ignored (so you can send to 'mike.smith' and 'mike_smith' and 'mikesmith' and they will all arrive at the same inbox (you will have to double check this as I am not sure enough to call that 'advice' :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Go to: `C:\ProgramData\Freedom Scientific\JAWS\2019\SETTINGS`
2. Edit the `.sbl` file corresponding to whatever synthesiser you happen to be using (eg, `eloq.sbl` for Eloquence).
3. Search for each occurrence of the word `underline` and replace it with `underscore`.
4. Save the file.
5. Restart JAWS.

Underlines should be spoken as underscores from now on.

HTH! :)